# how to get number of offline messages in Agsxmpp?

Tags: c#, xmpp, agsxmpp

I am using Agsxmpp to implement XMPP protocol and want to know number of Offline messages that was sent for me.
I know that by setting my state to available , sever send all offline messages, but I want to know number of offline message before come online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you server supports XEP-0013: Flexible Offline Message Retrieval you can retieve the number of offline messages like described here:
http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0013.html#request-number

Comment: Thanks Alex,if client request number of offline messages, server mark this messages as read or client must be receive all messages?

Comment: Why should a server mark a message as read which you have not received or read?

Comment: Ok, I can get number of offline messages and when set my state to Online server sent these messages. Thanks.